# Многопоточная обработка файлов

Tags: perl, многопоточность, linux

Добрый день,

Хочу сделать многопоточную обработку файлов. Проблема в том, что не соображу, как сделать, чтобы не сразу запускать N потоков, как [тут](http://nopox.wordpress.com/2007/11/06/multithreading-in-perl-part-2/). А чтобы работало, к примеру, 5 потоков и по мере их окончания запускались еще 5... и так пока не кончатся данные для обработки.
Подскажите, в виде общего каркаса кода.

```
use threads;
my @threads;
my @files=qw(1111.txt 2222.txt 3333.txt 4444.txt 5555.txt 6666.txt 7777.txt 88888.txt 99999.txt 000000.txt);
my $max_threads=5; # макс. число одновременно работающих потоков

foreach my $file (@files)
{
    push @threads, threads->create(\&getfile, $file); # так мы запустим потоков столько сколько записей в массиве, а надо типа очереди, чтото
}

foreach my $thread (@threads)
    {
    $thread->join();
    }

sub getfile{
my $file=shift;
print $file."\n";
}
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: «[Сколько потоков нужно для чтения файлов с диска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540616/208074)».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суммируя все вышесказанное:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w --

use strict;
use warnings;

package main;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

sub getfile {
    my $arg =  shift;

    while (my $file = shift @{ $arg }) {
        print threads->tid(), ': ', $file, "\n";
        threads->yield();
        sleep(1); # в реальной жизни - можно удалить
    }
}
sub main {
    my $max_threads = 5; # макс. число одновременно работающих потоков
    my @files :shared;
    my @t;

    @files = qw(1111.txt 2222.txt 3333.txt 4444.txt 5555.txt 6666.txt 7777.txt 8888.txt 9999.txt 0000.txt);
    for (1 .. $max_threads) {
        push(@t, threads->create( sub { getfile(\@files) } ));
    }
    $_->join foreach (@t);
    threads->exit();
}

&main;

1;
```

Comment: При таком подходе: все $max_threads потоков будут получать все файлы, которые перечисленны в files. Т.е в данном случае вы 5 раз получите 1111.txt и т.д. вопрос зачем такое нужно ?

Вернее еще не так. Есть вероятность что файл прочитается более 1го раза.

Comment: Вот вывод программы:

    1: 1111.txt
    2: 2222.txt
    3: 3333.txt
    4: 4444.txt
    5: 5555.txt
    ... тут пауза 1 сек.
    1: 6666.txt
    2: 7777.txt
    3: 8888.txt
    4: 9999.txt
    5: 0000.txt

Как следствие видно что каждый из потоков обработал два файла.
Если убрать `sleep(1)` из обработчика, то получаем:

    1: 1111.txt
    1: 2222.txt
    1: 3333.txt
    1: 4444.txt
    1: 5555.txt
    1: 6666.txt
    1: 7777.txt
    1: 8888.txt
    1: 9999.txt
    1: 0000.txt

То есть все файлы забрал первый поток

Answer (score 0):

Обрабатывай не 1 файл - 1 поток, а 1 поток - n/5 файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Создать `$max_threds` потоков, объявить `@files` как `shared` через `threads::shared` и использовать как очередь, извлекая в каждом потоке `while ( my $cfile = shift @files ) {}` пока очередь не опустеет.

Comment: А без threads::shared? у меня он нигде вообще не ставиться (perl 5.8.8)