# Сколько потоков нужно для чтения файлов с диска?

Tags: java, многопоточность, файлы

Имеется *400,000* xml-файлов. Вес большей части не превышает 2КБ. Java-приложение должно считать их с диска, обработать (сейчас используется stax парсер) и загрузить в различные коллекции.

**Сколько потоков нужно использовать для этой цели?** Одни люди говорят, что больше одного потока для чтения с диска использовать неэффективно, другие наоборот включают достаточно много потоков.

---

**Дополнено:**

@Arhad @KoVadim @Monk если запускать программу впервые (т.е. warmup'a нет), то у меня этот процесс занимает аж целый час, на других машинах - не больше 15 минут. После нескольких запусков у меня тоже где-то 15 минут обработка занимает. Вчера попробовал forkjoinpool (каждая папка уходит в отдельный тред) и fixedthreadpool (просто скидываю подряд все файлы в виде runnable-тасков) - толку ноль.

Выставлял 4 нити (столько ядер у процессора). Может можно как-то увеличить количество единоразовой подачи информации с диска в память, файлы ведь дефрагментированы, должны подряд идти непосредственно на носителе, если я правильно понимаю.

По поводу разделения логики: думал об этом в самом начале. Но вряд ли это можно применить к stax парсеру.

Comment: Думаю, вам подойдёт паттерн Producer-Consumer: один поток читает файлы и складывает их в потокобезопасную очередь, другие потоки выбирают их из очереди и парсят.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov да, неплохо было бы его заюзать, но не знаю, актуален ли он для stax-парсера?

Comment: При маленьких размерах файлов их проще читать в DOM и потом обрабатывать.

Comment: producer/consumer вообще все равно, какая логика в нем содержится. Главно, что есть обозначенные входы-выходы. А логика "преобразования" может быть любой.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если кратко, то универсального ответа на данный вопрос не существует. Вооружитесь профилировщиком и ищите максимум производительности среди различного количества одновременно открываемых файлов.

Дело в том, что:

- с одной стороны, HDD и SSD не могут быть опрошены одновременно в несколько потоков, даже если эти потоки принадлежат разным процессам;
- но с другой стороны, операционная система как правило делает *чтение на упреждение* в буфер, размещаемый в незанятой области ОЗУ. Однако предсказать удачность подобного кэширования практически невозможно из-за совокупности огромного количества постоянно меняющихся факторов.

Comment: думаю, тут даже профилировщик и не нужен. 400000 файлов загрузить - это вряд ли будет быстрее нескольких секунд. Поэтому можно мерить любым инструментом.
По поводу кол-ва тредов - думаю их будет либо кол-во ядер+1, либо кол-во ядер/2 + 1.

Answer (score 5):

Разделяйте логику. Грузите в одном потоке файлы, в другом - обрабатывайте загруженные.

Диск не будет простаивать, пока идёт обработка, как если бы вы работали в одном потоке, но и не будет пытаться в несколько потоков загружать файлы, что редко дает толк без низкоуровневой обработки.

Answer (score 0):

Много потоков какбы и не есть хорошо. 1 поток тоже не есть хорошо. У вас должна быть реализована нейкая системка, типо нейкая пара потоков читает(тоесть ожидает пока операционная система не предоставит данные с жесткого) 2.а вторая пара уже работает с парой данных которые предоставили из 1 потока. (но у вас еще декодинг да, думаю его в первую пару прикрепить).