# Как дождаться завершения работы ThreadPool

Tags: c#

Добрый день, подскажите как быть.

Есть программа, которая копирует множество файлов из одного места по сети в другое, очередь файлов на копирование собирается специфическим образом (в графическом интерфейсе человек отмечает множество папок и файлов галочками).

Для реализации самого копирования было решено не изобретать велосипед и воспользоваться классом из [интернет](http://www.bearnakedcode.com/2016/09/multi-threaded-asynchronous-file-copy.html)

В нем как раз копирование сделано через `ThreadPool`. Но я не понимаю как управлять этим `ThreadPool` т.е. как понять что копирование уже завершено? И еще момент - копирование через эти `ThreadPool` забивает канал и память, компьютер сильно зависает. Как-то можно ограничить эти параметры?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540616/208074

Answer (score 3):

Если вы пользуетесь библиотекой для копирования файлов — это она должна уметь сообщить вам, что копирование завершено. В противном случае это плохая, негодная библиотека, и вы должны сменить её на нормальную.

Пул потоков в .NET не *завершает работу* никогда, это служебная часть рантайм-библиотеки, которая доступна всегда, до окончания работы программы.

Я думаю, нет смысла копировать одновременно несколько файлов, т. к. вы упираетесь в производительность системы ввода-вывода. Попробуйте копировать файлы по одному, один за другим.

---

P. S.: А чем вас не устраивает стандартное копирование через `File.Copy`? Зачем нужна какая-то библиотека?

---

P. P. S.: Первое, что я увидел, открыв статью, на которую вы ссылаетесь — событие `FileCopyComplete`. Почему бы просто не подписаться на него?

Comment: Я совершенный новичок в этом деле (в с# и) , но как мне показалось FileCopyComplete говорит о завершении копирования одного файла, т.е. каждого файла. У меня файлов на копирование несколько тысяч, одновременное копирование файлов вроде как все-таки дает прирост производительности небольшой но он есть 5-20%. И при копировании в несколько часов - все таки это преимущество, собственно почему и не устраивало стандартное File.Copy

Comment: @АлексейРакушин: Ну заведите список файлов, которые вы копируете, и дождитесь окончания копирования каждого из них.

Comment: @АлексейРакушин: А если запустить несколько File.Copy параллельно в фоне?